# Docusign embedded signing using .net client

Tags: .net, client, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign-.NET-Client (https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client) to integrate embedded signing process in my website.

Our workflow is to create an envelope for a new user and then redirect them to sign the agreement. The envelope get created successfully. But after that when I try to redirect to signing page, it redirects me directly to return page.

Following is the code for creating envelope.

```
public static void CreateEnvelope()
        {
            //****** PARAMS *************************************************
            string AccountEmail = "******";
            string AccountPassword = "******";
            string RecipientEmail = "******";
            string RecipientName = "******";
            string TemplateRoleName = "******";
            //*****************************************************************

            const string integratorKey = "*******************";
            const string environment = "https://demo.docusign.net";
            bool result = false;
            var envelope = new Envelope();

            RestSettings.Instance.IntegratorKey = integratorKey;
            RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress = environment;
            RestSettings.Instance.WebServiceUrl = environment + "/restapi/v2";

            var account = new Account
            {
                Email = AccountEmail,
                Password = AccountPassword
            };


            if (!account.Login())
            {
                Debug.Print("Login API call failed for user {0}.\nError Code:  {1}\nMessage:  {2}", account.Email,
                    account.RestError.errorCode, account.RestError.message);

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // create envelope object and assign login info
                envelope = new Envelope
                {
                    Login = account,
                    TemplateId = "***********************",
                    TemplateRoles = new[]
                    {
                        new TemplateRole()
                        {
                            email = RecipientEmail,
                            name = RecipientName,
                            roleName = TemplateRoleName,
                            clientUserId = "C1E7D8B6-084A-402F-9BA8-014535D1F6C8"

                        }
                    },
                    EmailSubject = "Request",
                    Status = "sent"
                };

                result = envelope.Create();

                if (envelope.RestError != null)
                {
                    Debug.Print("Error code:  {0}\nMessage:  {1}", envelope.RestError.errorCode, envelope.RestError.message);
                    return;
                }

                bool res = envelope.GetSenderView("https://demo.docusign.net");
                if (!res)
                {
                    if (envelope.RestError != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error code:  {0}\nMessage:  {1}", envelope.RestError.errorCode, envelope.RestError.message);
                                return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered retrieving signing token, please review your envelope and recipient data.");
                                return false;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    // open the envelope's sending view
                        Process.Start(envelope.SenderViewUrl);
                 }
            }

            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason its automatically going to the redirect page is because you have set the status of the envelop to "Sent" which tells DocuSign to act on the redirect Url.

If you want the sender to view the draft before sending it remove the "Sent" status.
If you want to show them the view to sign the document call GetRecipientView() instead of GetSenderView()